# Can I use only input form for multiple form?

Tags: php, html

Can I use 1 input field for multiple for multiple form, this my idea but i don't know how to do it.

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" form="form1 form2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<form id="form2" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: it's not possible directly you can use `jQuery clone` method to get multiple forms with same elements

Comment: thanks, I think i should use javascript for this stack, merry x-mas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible with PHP for each loop. Put the form around your foreach loop but the submit button outside of your foreach loop and inside your form. You need to assign input value from array.

Comment: Your solution does not include mutliple forms, that share one input field with each other.